# Play sequence of animations on one view from onAnimationEnd

Tags: java, android, animation

I'm trying to play a sequence of more than 1 animations on the same progress bar. I am actually using a library called **AnimateHorizontalProgressBar** which allows the progress bars to fill up with an animation. The bar is an experience bar in a game, and if the player gets enough experience at one time, I want the bar to fill up as many times as there are level ups. (e.g. a level 1 character going to level 3 would have their experience bar fill up 2 full times, resetting whenever it gets full, then once more for however much progress they made from level 3 to level 4)

The solution I tried was to set an `AnimateProgressListener` on the **AnimateHorizontalProgressBar**, and in the `onAnimationEnd` function, to call the next animation to be played. The list containing these animations is an `arraylist` of custom POJOs which hold a reference to the view (the progress bar), and the percent to set it to.

```
public class MonsterBattleResolutionFragment extends MMOBaseFragment {


private static final String TAG = "Resolution Frag";

boolean isVictorious;
boolean playerCapturedMonster;

private String wildMonsterId;

ToolTipManager tooltips;

int monsterLevel;
private FirebaseFunctions mFunctions;

private ArrayList<String> monsterKeys;
private ArrayList<PlayerMonster> monstersList;

private BattleResolutionXpGainedAdapter battleResolutionXpGainedAdapter;
private Typeface typeface;

TextView victoryTextView;

private ListView xpGainedLayoutContainer;

private RecyclerView itemRecyclerView;
private PlayerItemAdapter playerItemAdapter;
ArrayList<PlayerItem> playerItems;

private FirebaseUser user;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_monster_battle_resolution, container, false);

    mFunctions = FirebaseFunctions.getInstance();
    typeface = CustomTypeFace.getNovemberTypeface(getContext());

    victoryTextView = view.findViewById(R.id.monster_battle_resolution_text_view);
    victoryTextView.setTypeface(typeface);

    tooltips = new ToolTipManager(getActivity());

    itemRecyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.monster_battle_resolution_item_recycler_view);
    itemRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    itemRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext()));

    playerItems = new ArrayList<>();
    playerItemAdapter = new PlayerItemAdapter(playerItems);
    itemRecyclerView.setAdapter(playerItemAdapter);

    isVictorious = getArguments().getBoolean("victory");
    playerCapturedMonster = getArguments().getBoolean("playerCapturedMonster");
    monsterLevel = getArguments().getInt("monsterLevel");
    monsterKeys = getArguments().getStringArrayList("monsterKeys");
    monstersList = getArguments().getParcelableArrayList("monstersList");

    for (int i = 0; i < monstersList.size(); i++){
        Log.e(TAG, monstersList.get(i).getMonsterStringName());
    }

    wildMonsterId = getArguments().getString("wildMonsterId");

    ArrayList<String> playerMonsterIds = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < monstersList.size(); i++){
        Log.e(TAG, "fb id is " + monstersList.get(i).getFirebaseId());
        playerMonsterIds.add(monstersList.get(i).getFirebaseId());
    }

    Task<HashMap<String, Integer>> test = firebaseResolveCombat(wildMonsterId, playerMonsterIds);
    test.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<HashMap<String, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<HashMap<String, Integer>> task) {
            Object gainedXp = task.getResult().get("experience");
            Object items = task.getResult().get("items");
            Object skills = task.getResult().get("skills");
            Object newMonsterLevels = task.getResult().get("newMonsterLevels");
            // gainedXp is the xp gained for each monster involved in the fight

            if (gainedXp != null){
                Log.e(TAG, "experience earned: " + gainedXp);
                updateXpBars((int) gainedXp);
            }

            if (items != null){
                Log.e(TAG, "items earned: " + items.toString());
                HashMap<String, Integer> itemsEarnedMap = (HashMap<String, Integer>) items;
                for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> item : itemsEarnedMap.entrySet()) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "key: " + item.getKey() + ", value: " + item.getValue());
                    // add new item to list for adapter. NOTE: as of now, key is a string, while value (quantity) is an int. slight issue on javascript side, fine for now.
                    playerItems.add(ItemDirectory.itemLookup(Integer.parseInt(item.getKey()), item.getValue()));
                }
            }

            if (skills != null){
                Log.e(TAG, "new skills: " + skills.toString());
                HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> newSkills = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>) skills;

                for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> item : newSkills.entrySet()) {

                    for (Integer skill : item.getValue()) {
                        String skillName = SkillDirectory.skillLookup(skill).getName();
                        Log.e(TAG, item.getKey() + " learned skill " + skillName);


                        for (int i = 0; i < monstersList.size(); i++){
                            Log.e(TAG, "fb id is " + monstersList.get(i).getFirebaseId());
                            if (monstersList.get(i).getFirebaseId().equals(item.getKey())){
                                Toast.makeText(getContext(), monstersList.get(i).getMonsterStringName() + " learned skill " + skillName + "!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }

                    }

                }
            }

            if (newMonsterLevels != null){
                Log.e(TAG, "new levels: " + newMonsterLevels.toString());
            }

        }
    });

    xpGainedLayoutContainer = view.findViewById(R.id.monster_battle_resolution_xp_gained_layout_container);

    battleResolutionXpGainedAdapter = new BattleResolutionXpGainedAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.battle_resolution_xp_gained_layout, monstersList);
    xpGainedLayoutContainer.setAdapter(battleResolutionXpGainedAdapter);
    justifyListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(xpGainedLayoutContainer);

    // if the player did not win, don't show items won, give them half xp
    if (!isVictorious) {
        victoryTextView.setText(R.string.defeat);
    }

    // listener for button to return to map
    FloatingActionButton b = view.findViewById(R.id.monster_battle_resolution_return_to_map_button);
    b.setOnClickListener(view1 -> {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
    });

    return view;
}

private void updateXpBars(int xpPerMonster){

    ArrayList<LevelUpBarAnimation> animationList = new ArrayList<>();

    // First build the list of animations
    Log.e(TAG, "There are " + battleResolutionXpGainedAdapter.getCount() + " xp bars to animate");
    for (int i = 0; i < battleResolutionXpGainedAdapter.getCount(); i++){

        int currentXp = monstersList.get(i).getExperience();
        int level = monstersList.get(i).getLevel();
        int newXp = currentXp + xpPerMonster;
        int lastLevelXp = getExperienceRequiredForNextLevel(level-1);
        boolean isLevelUp = false;

        int xpNumerator = newXp - lastLevelXp;
        int xpDenominator = getExperienceRequiredForNextLevel(level) - lastLevelXp;

        Log.e(TAG, "Monster was level: " + level + ", and had " + currentXp + " xp");
        Log.e(TAG, "now has " + newXp + " xp. level now: " + getLevelBasedOnExperience(newXp));

        // In a loop, build up every animation which needs to be done on this particular xp bar. Loop is so multiple animations may be played for multiple level ups\
        // do while because even when the monster does not level up, they still will get some xp so at least 1 anim needs to be played
        do {
            isLevelUp = false;  // Need to reset to know when we have not leveled up

            AnimateHorizontalProgressBar bar = xpGainedLayoutContainer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.battle_resolution_xp_gained_xp_bar);
            bar.setMax(10000);

            if (newXp > getExperienceRequiredForNextLevel(level)){
                isLevelUp = true;
                level++;
                xpNumerator = xpDenominator;    // Sets the xp bar to full before resetting at 0 for the next level
            }

            Log.e(TAG, "Added new anim for bar at position " + i + ", " + "out of 10000: " + (int) (((double) xpNumerator / (double) xpDenominator) * 10000.0));

            // TODO: clean up messy cast
            LevelUpBarAnimation levelUpBarAnimation = new LevelUpBarAnimation(bar, (int) (((double) xpNumerator / (double) xpDenominator) * 10000.0), level);
            levelUpBarAnimation.setLevelUp(isLevelUp);

            Log.e(TAG, "islevelup set to " + String.valueOf(levelUpBarAnimation.isLevelUp()) + ", going from level " + (level-1) + " to " + (level));
            levelUpBarAnimation.setLevelTxtView(xpGainedLayoutContainer.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.battle_resolution_xp_gained_level_text_view));

            animationList.add(levelUpBarAnimation);

        } while(isLevelUp);

    }

    final int[] animNumber = {0};

    Log.e(TAG, "animlist size " + animationList.size() + " playing across " + battleResolutionXpGainedAdapter.getCount() + " xp bars");
    for (int i = 0; i < battleResolutionXpGainedAdapter.getCount(); i++) {

        AnimateHorizontalProgressBar bar = animationList.get(i).getXpBar();

        bar.setAnimateProgressListener(new AnimateHorizontalProgressBar.AnimateProgressListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(int progress, int max) {

                Log.e(TAG, "anim #" + animNumber[0] + " starting");

            }
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(int progress, int max) {

                // If this xp bar filled up, play a flash sort of animation, and update the lvl text
                if (animationList.get(animNumber[0]).isLevelUp()){

                    int newLvl = animationList.get(animNumber[0]).getLevel();

                    Log.e(TAG, "level up animation playing. anim number " + animNumber[0] + ", now level " + newLvl);
                    // Update the lvl txt
                    animationList.get(animNumber[0]).getLevelTxtView().setText("LVL: " + newLvl);

                    // Then set the progress on this bar back to 0
                    animationList.get(animNumber[0]).getXpBar().setProgress(0);
                }

                Log.e(TAG, "anim number " + animNumber[0] + " finished, next playing " + (animNumber[0] + 1));

                // Do not attempt to play the next animation if this one was the last
                if (animNumber[0] < animationList.size() - 1){
                    animNumber[0]++;
                    Log.e(TAG, "playing anim number " + animNumber[0] + " to " + animationList.get(animNumber[0]).getProgressPercent() + "% full");
                    animationList.get(animNumber[0]).getXpBar().setProgressWithAnim(animationList.get(animNumber[0]).getProgressPercent());  // TODO: this not getting called
                }
            }
        });
    }

    Log.e(TAG, "playing anim number 0");
    animationList.get(0).getXpBar().setProgressWithAnim(animationList.get(0).getProgressPercent());

}

// On receiving a new skill, this tooltip will appear momentarily to notify the player
public void showNewSkillTooltip(String skillName, View view) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Showing new skill tooltip. skill learned: " + skillName);

    // Dynamically build a layout here, as it cannot already have a parent layout if we want to assign it to the tooltip
    LinearLayout tooltipLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
    tooltipLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

    TextView talentTitleText = new TextView(getContext());
    talentTitleText.setTextSize(18f);
    talentTitleText.setText(skillName);
    tooltipLayout.addView(talentTitleText);

    ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip()
            .withColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.grey_300)) //or whatever you want
            .withAnimationType(ToolTip.AnimationType.FROM_MASTER_VIEW)
            .withContentView(tooltipLayout)
            .withShadow();
    tooltips.showToolTip(toolTip, view);

}

private Task<HashMap<String, Integer>> firebaseResolveCombat(String wildMonsterFirebaseId, ArrayList<String> playerMonsterIds) {
    // Create the arguments to the callable function.
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<>();
    data.put("wildMonsterId", wildMonsterFirebaseId);
    data.put("playerMonsterIds", playerMonsterIds);

    return mFunctions
            .getHttpsCallable("resolveWildMonsterCombat")
            .call(data)
            .continueWith(new Continuation<HttpsCallableResult, HashMap<String, Integer>>() {
                @Override
                public HashMap then(@NonNull Task<HttpsCallableResult> task) throws Exception {
                    // This continuation runs on either success or failure, but if the task
                    // has failed then getResult() will throw an Exception which will be
                    // propagated down.
                    HashMap<String, Integer> result = (HashMap<String, Integer>) task.getResult().getData();
                    return result;
                }
            });
}
}
```

I added the whole class. Forgive the messy code.

The problem is that after the first animation which I start explicitly, it runs the onAnimationEnd function, and hits the line to run the next animation, but it never starts. The onAnimationStart function is never even called for the 2nd animation. Any ideas on why this might be?

I'll also add this takes place in a dialog fragment. Not sure if that is relevant however.

Comment: Where have you written animation.start() ?

Comment: The call on the bottom line to setProgressWithAnim starts the first animation. This first animation runs fine, and the onAnimationEnd is called afterwards, but none of the subsequent animations work.

Comment: Can you post all your class?